# Singleton variables are not persisting across system

Tags: java, singleton, persistence

I'm trying to play around with the singleton pattern in Java, but have run into an issue. I have a singleton `ClientCounter` that I want to keep track of instances of another class `Client`.

`ClientCounter` does so by simply incrementing a `count` whenever `Client` calls its `addClient()` method:

```
public class ClientCounter {

    private int count = 0;

    private static final ClientCounter counter = new ClientCounter();

    public static ClientCounter getInstance() {
        return counter;
    }

    public void addClient() {
        count++;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

}
```

My `Client` code:

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ClientCounter myCC = ClientCounter.getInstance();
        myCC.addClient();

        System.out.println("CC Count is " + myCC.getCount());

    }

}
```

However, my `count` doesn't seem to be persisting, as when I try to run two `Client`'s (in separate terminals), one after the other,  my output for both is:

```
CC Count is 1
```

Am I "doing" Singletons wrong, or is there some bug with my code?

Comment: They are global in a single Java Virtual Machine instance; they are not global across disparate virtual machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, my count doesn't seem to be persisting, as when I try to run two Client's (in separate terminals)

By definition, [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) will maintain a single instance of the object across *the system*. In this case, *the system* is your current application, so if you execute it multiple times, there would be multiple instances of your application, and each singleton object is tied to each application. In case of Java applications, each Java application is tied to the JVM; this doesn't apply for web applications, where the Java application is the application server, and the application server is tied to the JVM (in web applications the behavior of singleton is more complicated than this, but it is outside the scope of this question/answer).

In case you want to persist the value across multiple executions of your application, you should store the data in a data source common to your applications/terminals, probably in a shared file or in a database, and retrieve it from there multiple times. But note that this **is not** the work of a singleton and you probably will over complicate things by using this approach.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot of sense!

Answer (score 0):

Your Singleton implementation is missing a *private constructor*, so as written, other code can create arbitrary instances of it.  You can fix it by adding the private constructor to prevent other classes from constructing it.

```
public class ClientCounter {
     private ClientCounter() {}
}
```

However, even if it was correct, you cannot expect any state to persist **across processes** if there is no explicit communication between them.

If you are running two applications in two separate terminals, they have completely separate virtual address spaces for memory, and are for all intents and purposes isolated from each other.

If you wanted to persist data across multiple *instances* of your application, you need to set up a server process to keep this state, and have every client talk to the server process when it starts. Alternatively, they could all access a shared data store (such as a database) to synchronize.

Comment: "There is nothing wrong with your Singleton implementation" Actually yes there is. There is nothing in the class that makes it a singleton--many unique instances of "ClientCounter" can be created. A private constructor should be defined in order to make it a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

"when I try to run two Client's (in separate terminals)" I assume you mean you are running your java application twice? If so, singleton applies to a single JVM (i.e. execution of a java program, just to be brief).

Answer (score 0):

A singleton is normally linked to a `ClassLoader` only. In your case since you are running 2 separate Java VM, so they are bound to be different singleton objects in these 2 virtual machines.